# File extension validation

Tags: vba

This searches for the end of a file name removes it's current file type of .docm and converts it to a .docx.  Works great.

```
  ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Left(ActiveDocument.Name, InStrRev(ActiveDocument.Name, ".") - 1), WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument
```

However, I noticed a little bug.  If there is a . in the file name, it finds that first and obviously creates a file that is incorrect.

For example:
TestFileV1.2AlexTest.docm

Becomes the file 
TestFileV.2AlextTest  Where the new file type is a .2ALEXTEST file.

Kind of a funny error, but still a bug none the less.

Best course of action for validation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try the VBA.Strings.Split() function, which splits a string into an array.

Split the File name on '.' and the last element in the array will be your extension:

```
Public Function GetExtension(FileName As String) As String
'Returns a file's extension 

' This does not go to the filesystem and get the file:
' The function parses out the string after the last '.'
' Useful for situations where a file does not yet exist 
 
' Nigel Heffernan   Excellerando.Blogspot.com
' **** THIS CODE IS IN THE PUBLIC DOMAIN ****  
 
'Print GetExtension("C:\Temp\data.txt1.docx")
'Returns docx  
 
Dim arrayX() As String
Dim iLast As Integer  
 
    arrayX = Split(FileName, ".")
    iLast = UBound(arrayX)  
 
    GetExtension = arrayX(iLast) 
 
    Erase arrayX  
 
End Function
```

If you don't care about readability, the quick-and-dirty answer is:

`strExt = Split(strFile, ".")(UBound(Split(strFile, ".")))`

However... I think you're looking for something more sophisticated than a string parser to extract the file extension.

**Are you actually looking to validate the file extension?**

I'm not coding up a registry lookup for the ShellExt application command to open your file, but I had a closely-related issue to yours a year or two ago, when I needed to populate a file dialog's filter list with a list of arbitrary file extensions.

It doesn't 'validate' as such, but unknown extensions will return a string containing 'unknown file type', and you can test for that:

#### VBA and the Registry: Returning a File Type from a File Extension

```
Public Function GetExtensionType(strExt As String) As String

' Return a file extension type descriptor, if the OS knows it
' Parses out the string after the last "." and reads the registry

' GetExtensionType("txt")                   Returns 'Text Document'
' GetExtensionType("SystemORA.user.config") 'XML Configuration File'
' GetExtensionType("Phishy.vbs")            'VBScript Script File'


' Nigel Heffernan   Excellerando.Blogspot.com
' **** THIS CODE IS IN THE PUBLIC DOMAIN ****  


On Error GoTo ErrSub

Dim strType As String
Dim strTyp1 As String
Dim strTyp2 As String

strExt = Trim(strExt)

' Set a default return: if an error is raised, return this value 
GetExtensionType = Trim(strExt & " (unknown file type)")

strExt = Split(strExt, ".")(UBound(Split(strExt, ".")))  '

If strExt = "" Then
    Exit Function
End If

With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'   This will go to error if there's no key for strExt in HKCR
    strTyp1 = .RegRead("HKCR." & strExt & "\")

    If strTyp1 = "" Then
        strType = strExt & " File"
    Else
    '   This value isn't very readable, eg: Access.ACCDEFile.14
    '   But we can use it to retrieve a descriptive string:
        strTyp2 = .RegRead("HKCR\" & strTyp1 & "\")
        
        If strTyp2 = "" Then
        '   So we didn't get a descriptive string: 
        '   Parse some readability out of strType1:
            strType = strTyp1
            strType = Replace(strType, "File", " File")
            strType = Replace(strType, ".", " ")
        Else
            strType = strTyp2
        End If
        
    End If
    
End With

If strType <> "" Then
    GetExtensionType = strType
End If

ExitSub:
    Exit Function
ErrSub:
    Resume ExitSub

End Function
```

I made it error-tolerant but I didn't bother idiot-proofing it because someone, somewhere, is building a better idiot; and it's entirely possible that the user was actually right insofar as there really are files called that, and my system didn't have a registry entry for the file type in question.

There is an obvious source of errors in the code: `GetExtensionType("docx")` will give you 'Microsoft Word Document' on an *English-Language* workstation. If your user base are working with other languages and locales, they will see the descriptive name 'Microsoft Word Document' in their chosen language; and any validation logic you've coded up will fail to match that string (unless, of course, your string literals are internationalised in a conditional compiler block).

So any validation against a predefined application name or file type needs to be at the language-independent layer of the registry, using 'strTyp1' from the root instead of the locale-dependent strings passed into 'strTyp2'.

Answer (score 1):

Use the FileSystemObject from the Scripting Runtime - it has a `.GetBaseName()` method to extract the basename from a file path:

```
'Early bound (reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime):
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 fso.GetBaseName(ActiveDocument.Name), WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument

'Late bound:
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 fso.GetBaseName(ActiveDocument.Name), WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument
```

You can also retrieve the extension with the `.GetExtensionName()` method, the path with `.GetParentFolderName()`, and the drive letter with `GetDriveName()` (which also works with UNC paths).

If you need to find the registered name of the extension in the current Windows install, you can either use the registry method @Nile answered with or an API call to [AssocQueryStringA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773471%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
Const ASSOCSTR_FRIENDLYDOCNAME = 3

Private Declare Function AssocQueryString Lib "shlwapi.dll" _
    Alias "AssocQueryStringA" ( _
    ByRef Flags As Long, _
    ByVal str As Long, _
    ByVal pszAssoc As String, _
    ByVal pszExtra As String, _
    ByVal pszOut As String, _
    ByRef pcchOut As Long) As Long

Sub Main()

    Dim buffer As String
    buffer = String$(255, " ")
    Dim hresult As Long
    hresult = AssocQueryString(0, ASSOCSTR_FRIENDLYDOCNAME, ".docm", _
                               vbNullString, buffer, 255)

    If hresult = 0 Then
        'Should be something like "Microsoft Word Macro-Enabled Document"
        Debug.Print Trim$(buffer)
    End If

End Sub
```

Note that you can also retrieve addition information about the associated file type by passing different values for the `str` parameter.  See the [ASSOCSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) enumeration.

Comment: That's good, if you have the file. The question asks for validation of a file *extension* and it's an interesting distinction, because there are circumstances when you want to check before the file has been created.

Comment: @Nile - The FSO parsing methods take strings, not files, so they can be for validation before writing a file. I may have misunderstood the part of the file the OP was interested in though, will edit when I'm not on my phone.

Comment: Pretty good: FSO.GetExtensionName() parses out the extension, too: I may start using that instead of string-handling. However, that only takes us as far as parsing out the extension string: querying the file *type* and validating it needs another step. In FSO, that's **GetFile("C:\Temp\Foo.doc").Type** - and you'll only get  "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document" from that if a Scripting.File object can be instantiated by GetFile().